# Assign cell as sheet name in the data range of a chart (Excel)

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula

I'm currently using multiple sheets of data, while the sheet names are the corresponding dates. As I don't want to add a chart to every sheet, I decided to create a single sheet containing one chart and an additional sheet containing a reference cell that I'd like to use when selecting the data range of the chart.
I'm trying to replace the "10.01.18" in the formula "='10.01.18'!$B$1" with the cell containing a certain date, leading to the chart dynamically changing the data range as the date in the corresponding cell is changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: posting your code generally helps.

Comment: I don't have any code yet, I'm generally trying to fix it by using a formula to replace "10.01.18".

Comment: Might be better to use one sheet with multiple dates. With multiple sheets you'll have to use the volatile `INDIRECT` to build your references.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,2,,,TEXT(A2,"dd.mm.yy")))
```

Where A2 is the cell containing the date. The text function reformats the date as text in the right format, then the address function produces a cell reference. Indirect turns the text cell reference into a live reference.

Comment: Seems like a good idea but Excel returns "That function is not valid" when I try to use the formula within the "Select Data Source" settings for my graph.

Comment: True. Some functions are not allowed in a chart source. I would use this formula to mirror your data on a given sheet in an organized way, and then point your chart source to the clean version.